# Flexbox list items - equal height nested list items

Tags: css, flexbox

I want equal size nested list items. Here is the example code am working on

```css
ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>menu item 1</li>
  <li>menu item 2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>sub-menu item 1</li>
      <li>sub-menu item 2</li>
      <li>sub-menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>menu item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am getting equal height of all menu items but not for sub-menu items. All menu items and submenu items should have equal height. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this show in the fiddle below you can give some min-height to li blocks like below and in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cpvwmz8/6/).

```
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  min-height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column` to the nested lists.

```css
ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; /* new */
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>menu item 1</li>
  <li>menu item 2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>sub-menu item 1</li>
      <li>sub-menu item 2</li>
      <li>sub-menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>menu item 3</li>
</ul>
```